# Function to insert a specific formula excel VBA (decimal to fractional inches)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of distances that I would like to display like you would read off a tape measure, for example 144.125 would display as 144 1/8". I have the following formula

```
=TEXT(A1,"0"&IF(ABS(A1-ROUND(A1,0))>1/32,"0/"&CHOOSE(ROUND(MOD(A1,1)*16,0),16,8,16,4,16,8,16,2,16,8,16,4,16,8,16),""))&""""
```

I'd like to simplify it to a 1 argument function (for A1) so I could use it throughout the workbook, but the amount of " quotes and vba keywords is causing problems. Is there an easier way to get a UDF to insert a complicated formula?

Comment: Can't you just use a custom number format like # ??/??\" and enter the numbers directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a `UDF` with visual basic then try this:

```
Public Function Fraction(ByVal x As Double, Optional ByVal tol As Double = 1 / 64#) As String
    Dim s As Long, w As Long, d As Long, n As Long, f As Double
    s = Sgn(x): x = Abs(x)
    If s = 0 Then
        Fraction = "0"
        Exit Function
    End If
    w = CInt(WorksheetFunction.Floor_Precise(x)): f = x - w
    d = CInt(WorksheetFunction.Floor_Precise(1 / tol)): n = WorksheetFunction.Round(f * d, 0)

    Dim g As Long
    Do
        g = WorksheetFunction.Gcd(n, d)
        n = n / g
        d = d / g
    Loop While Abs(g) > 1

    Fraction = Trim(IIf(s < 0, "-", vbNullString) + CStr(w) + IIf(n > 0, " " + CStr(n) + "/" + CStr(d), vbNullString))
End Function
```

With results:

[image: PIC]

Comment: Note you can bias the denominator by specifying a second argument to fraction (with tolerance amount) as `1/64`, `1/60`, `1/50` for powers 2, 3 and 5 respectively.

Comment: 20 years ago I had to manually calculate and make my own hand written chart for my engineering class.  This just took me way back, lol.

Comment: The power of programming ... let the computer do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The TEXT function can do this directly:

```
      A          B
1 144,1250    144 1/8 "
```

Formula in B1:

```
=TEXT(A1;"# ??/??\""")
```

Greetings

Axel